# Jetty 8.1.1.v20120215 in Eclipse with webapp (JSF + Maven)

Tags: eclipse, jsf, maven, jetty, maven-jetty-plugin

I am trying to run my webapp (using JSf) Jetty 8.1.1.v20120215 in Eclipse. I downloade Jettey Adaptor for Jetty and then added Jetty Server 8.1 in Eclipse. Then I stared my webapp under Jetty webserver. And got follwoing error. From statck trace it looks like Jetting is not getting some of the required jars. As have adde all those jar in my webapp in dependanceis as I am using maven. I can also see in eclipse those file listed in Eclipse under Refrenced Libaries.

```
2012-03-01 16:46:00.492:INFO:oejs.Server:jetty-8.1.1.v20120215
2012-03-01 16:46:00.515:INFO:oejdp.ScanningAppProvider:Deployment monitor /home/mitesh.patel/dev/mc-sandbox/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp1/webapps at interval 1
2012-03-01 16:46:00.519:INFO:oejdp.ScanningAppProvider:Deployment monitor /home/mitesh.patel/dev/mc-sandbox/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp1/contexts at interval 1
2012-03-01 16:46:00.521:INFO:oejd.DeploymentManager:Deployable added: /home/mitesh.patel/dev/mc-sandbox/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp1/contexts/mc-webapp.xml
2012-03-01 16:46:03.223:WARN:oejuc.AbstractLifeCycle:FAILED o.e.j.w.WebAppContext{/mc-webapp,[file:/home/mitesh.patel/dev/mc-sandbox/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp1/wtpwebapps/mc-webapp/, jar:file:/home/mitesh.patel/dev/mc-sandbox/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp1/wtpwebapps/mc-webapp/WEB-INF/lib/blitzer-1.0.3.jar!/META-INF/resources/, jar:file:/home/mitesh.patel/dev/mc-sandbox/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp1/wtpwebapps/mc-webapp/WEB-INF/lib/dark-hive-1.0.3.jar!/META-INF/resources/, jar:file:/home/mitesh.patel/dev/mc-sandbox/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp1/wtpwebapps/mc-webapp/WEB-INF/lib/ui-lightness-1.0.3.jar!/META-INF/resources/, jar:file:/home/mitesh.patel/dev/mc-sandbox/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp1/wtpwebapps/mc-webapp/WEB-INF/lib/sam-1.0.3.jar!/META-INF/resources/, jar:file:/home/mitesh.patel/dev/mc-sandbox/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp1/wtpwebapps/mc-webapp/WEB-INF/lib/rocket-1.0.3.jar!/META-INF/resources/, jar:file:/home/mitesh.patel/dev/mc-sandbox/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp1/wtpwebapps/mc-webapp/WEB-INF/lib/myfaces-api-2.1.5.jar!/META-INF/resources/, jar:file:/home/mitesh.patel/dev/mc-sandbox/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp1/wtpwebapps/mc-webapp/WEB-INF/lib/swanky-purse-1.0.3.jar!/META-INF/resources/, jar:file:/home/mitesh.patel/dev/mc-sandbox/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp1/wtpwebapps/mc-webapp/WEB-INF/lib/trontastic-1.0.3.jar!/META-INF/resources/, jar:file:/home/mitesh.patel/dev/mc-sandbox/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp1/wtpwebapps/mc-webapp/WEB-INF/lib/south-street-1.0.3.jar!/META-INF/resources/, jar:file:/home/mitesh.patel/dev/mc-sandbox/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp1/wtpwebapps/mc-webapp/WEB-INF/lib/primefaces-3.0.1.jar!/META-INF/resources/, jar:file:/home/mitesh.patel/dev/mc-sandbox/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp1/wtpwebapps/mc-webapp/WEB-INF/lib/hot-sneaks-1.0.3.jar!/META-INF/resources/, jar:file:/home/mitesh.patel/dev/mc-sandbox/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp1/wtpwebapps/mc-webapp/WEB-INF/lib/glass-x-1.0.3.jar!/META-INF/resources/, jar:file:/home/mitesh.patel/dev/mc-sandbox/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp1/wtpwebapps/mc-webapp/WEB-INF/lib/le-frog-1.0.3.jar!/META-INF/resources/, jar:file:/home/mitesh.patel/dev/mc-sandbox/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp1/wtpwebapps/mc-webapp/WEB-INF/lib/casablanca-1.0.3.jar!/META-INF/resources/, jar:file:/home/mitesh.patel/dev/mc-sandbox/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp1/wtpwebapps/mc-webapp/WEB-INF/lib/overcast-1.0.3.jar!/META-INF/resources/, jar:file:/home/mitesh.patel/dev/mc-sandbox/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp1/wtpwebapps/mc-webapp/WEB-INF/lib/ui-darkness-1.0.3.jar!/META-INF/resources/, jar:file:/home/mitesh.patel/dev/mc-sandbox/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp1/wtpwebapps/mc-webapp/WEB-INF/lib/midnight-1.0.3.jar!/META-INF/resources/, jar:file:/home/mitesh.patel/dev/mc-sandbox/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp1/wtpwebapps/mc-webapp/WEB-INF/lib/eggplant-1.0.3.jar!/META-INF/resources/, jar:file:/home/mitesh.patel/dev/mc-sandbox/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp1/wtpwebapps/mc-webapp/WEB-INF/lib/humanity-1.0.3.jar!/META-INF/resources/, jar:file:/home/mitesh.patel/dev/mc-sandbox/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp1/wtpwebapps/mc-webapp/WEB-INF/lib/smoothness-1.0.3.jar!/META-INF/resources/, jar:file:/home/mitesh.patel/dev/mc-sandbox/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp1/wtpwebapps/mc-webapp/WEB-INF/lib/flick-1.0.3.jar!/META-INF/resources/, jar:file:/home/mitesh.patel/dev/mc-sandbox/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp1/wtpwebapps/mc-webapp/WEB-INF/lib/vader-1.0.3.jar!/META-INF/resources/, jar:file:/home/mitesh.patel/dev/mc-sandbox/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp1/wtpwebapps/mc-webapp/WEB-INF/lib/cupertino-1.0.3.jar!/META-INF/resources/, jar:file:/home/mitesh.patel/dev/mc-sandbox/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp1/wtpwebapps/mc-webapp/WEB-INF/lib/black-tie-1.0.3.jar!/META-INF/resources/, jar:file:/home/mitesh.patel/dev/mc-sandbox/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp1/wtpwebapps/mc-webapp/WEB-INF/lib/bluesky-1.0.3.jar!/META-INF/resources/, jar:file:/home/mitesh.patel/dev/mc-sandbox/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp1/wtpwebapps/mc-webapp/WEB-INF/lib/pepper-grinder-1.0.3.jar!/META-INF/resources/, jar:file:/home/mitesh.patel/dev/mc-sandbox/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp1/wtpwebapps/mc-webapp/WEB-INF/lib/mc-theme.jar!/META-INF/resources/, jar:file:/home/mitesh.patel/dev/mc-sandbox/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp1/wtpwebapps/mc-webapp/WEB-INF/lib/home-1.0.3.jar!/META-INF/resources/, jar:file:/home/mitesh.patel/dev/mc-sandbox/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp1/wtpwebapps/mc-webapp/WEB-INF/lib/mint-choc-1.0.3.jar!/META-INF/resources/, jar:file:/home/mitesh.patel/dev/mc-sandbox/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp1/wtpwebapps/mc-webapp/WEB-INF/lib/sunny-1.0.3.jar!/META-INF/resources/, jar:file:/home/mitesh.patel/dev/mc-sandbox/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp1/wtpwebapps/mc-webapp/WEB-INF/lib/excite-bike-1.0.3.jar!/META-INF/resources/, jar:file:/home/mitesh.patel/dev/mc-sandbox/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp1/wtpwebapps/mc-webapp/WEB-INF/lib/start-1.0.3.jar!/META-INF/resources/, jar:file:/home/mitesh.patel/dev/mc-sandbox/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp1/wtpwebapps/mc-webapp/WEB-INF/lib/redmond-1.0.3.jar!/META-INF/resources/, jar:file:/home/mitesh.patel/dev/mc-sandbox/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp1/wtpwebapps/mc-webapp/WEB-INF/lib/myfaces-impl-2.1.5.jar!/META-INF/resources/]},/home/mitesh.patel/dev/mc-sandbox/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp1/wtpwebapps/mc-webapp: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/objectweb/asm/ClassVisitor
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/objectweb/asm/ClassVisitor
    at org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationConfiguration.createAnnotationParser(AnnotationConfiguration.java:111)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationConfiguration.configure(AnnotationConfiguration.java:73)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.configure(WebAppContext.java:428)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1208)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:699)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:454)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:59)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.bindings.StandardStarter.processBinding(StandardStarter.java:36)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.AppLifeCycle.runBindings(AppLifeCycle.java:183)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.DeploymentManager.requestAppGoal(DeploymentManager.java:491)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.DeploymentManager.addApp(DeploymentManager.java:138)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.providers.ScanningAppProvider.fileAdded(ScanningAppProvider.java:142)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.providers.ScanningAppProvider$1.fileAdded(ScanningAppProvider.java:53)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.reportAddition(Scanner.java:604)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.reportDifferences(Scanner.java:535)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.scan(Scanner.java:398)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.doStart(Scanner.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:59)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.providers.ScanningAppProvider.doStart(ScanningAppProvider.java:118)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:59)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.DeploymentManager.startAppProvider(DeploymentManager.java:552)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.DeploymentManager.doStart(DeploymentManager.java:227)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:59)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AggregateLifeCycle.doStart(AggregateLifeCycle.java:58)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:53)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.doStart(HandlerWrapper.java:91)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:263)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:59)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration$1.run(XmlConfiguration.java:1215)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration.main(XmlConfiguration.java:1138)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.start.Main.invokeMain(Main.java:457)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.start.Main.start(Main.java:602)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.start.Main.main(Main.java:82)
Caused by: 
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.objectweb.asm.ClassVisitor
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationConfiguration.createAnnotationParser(AnnotationConfiguration.java:111)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationConfiguration.configure(AnnotationConfiguration.java:73)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.configure(WebAppContext.java:428)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1208)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:699)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:454)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:59)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.bindings.StandardStarter.processBinding(StandardStarter.java:36)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.AppLifeCycle.runBindings(AppLifeCycle.java:183)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.DeploymentManager.requestAppGoal(DeploymentManager.java:491)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.DeploymentManager.addApp(DeploymentManager.java:138)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.providers.ScanningAppProvider.fileAdded(ScanningAppProvider.java:142)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.providers.ScanningAppProvider$1.fileAdded(ScanningAppProvider.java:53)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.reportAddition(Scanner.java:604)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.reportDifferences(Scanner.java:535)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.scan(Scanner.java:398)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.doStart(Scanner.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:59)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.providers.ScanningAppProvider.doStart(ScanningAppProvider.java:118)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:59)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.DeploymentManager.startAppProvider(DeploymentManager.java:552)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.DeploymentManager.doStart(DeploymentManager.java:227)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:59)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AggregateLifeCycle.doStart(AggregateLifeCycle.java:58)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:53)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.doStart(HandlerWrapper.java:91)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:263)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:59)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration$1.run(XmlConfiguration.java:1215)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration.main(XmlConfiguration.java:1138)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.start.Main.invokeMain(Main.java:457)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.start.Main.start(Main.java:602)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.start.Main.main(Main.java:82)
2012-03-01 16:46:03.226:WARN:oejd.DeploymentManager:Unable to reach node goal: started
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/objectweb/asm/ClassVisitor
    at org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationConfiguration.createAnnotationParser(AnnotationConfiguration.java:111)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationConfiguration.configure(AnnotationConfiguration.java:73)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.configure(WebAppContext.java:428)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1208)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:699)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:454)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:59)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.bindings.StandardStarter.processBinding(StandardStarter.java:36)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.AppLifeCycle.runBindings(AppLifeCycle.java:183)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.DeploymentManager.requestAppGoal(DeploymentManager.java:491)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.DeploymentManager.addApp(DeploymentManager.java:138)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.providers.ScanningAppProvider.fileAdded(ScanningAppProvider.java:142)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.providers.ScanningAppProvider$1.fileAdded(ScanningAppProvider.java:53)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.reportAddition(Scanner.java:604)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.reportDifferences(Scanner.java:535)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.scan(Scanner.java:398)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.doStart(Scanner.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:59)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.providers.ScanningAppProvider.doStart(ScanningAppProvider.java:118)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:59)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.DeploymentManager.startAppProvider(DeploymentManager.java:552)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.DeploymentManager.doStart(DeploymentManager.java:227)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:59)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AggregateLifeCycle.doStart(AggregateLifeCycle.java:58)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:53)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.doStart(HandlerWrapper.java:91)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:263)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:59)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration$1.run(XmlConfiguration.java:1215)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration.main(XmlConfiguration.java:1138)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.start.Main.invokeMain(Main.java:457)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.start.Main.start(Main.java:602)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.start.Main.main(Main.java:82)
Caused by: 
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.objectweb.asm.ClassVisitor
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationConfiguration.createAnnotationParser(AnnotationConfiguration.java:111)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationConfiguration.configure(AnnotationConfiguration.java:73)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.configure(WebAppContext.java:428)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1208)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:699)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:454)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:59)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.bindings.StandardStarter.processBinding(StandardStarter.java:36)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.AppLifeCycle.runBindings(AppLifeCycle.java:183)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.DeploymentManager.requestAppGoal(DeploymentManager.java:491)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.DeploymentManager.addApp(DeploymentManager.java:138)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.providers.ScanningAppProvider.fileAdded(ScanningAppProvider.java:142)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.providers.ScanningAppProvider$1.fileAdded(ScanningAppProvider.java:53)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.reportAddition(Scanner.java:604)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.reportDifferences(Scanner.java:535)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.scan(Scanner.java:398)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.doStart(Scanner.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:59)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.providers.ScanningAppProvider.doStart(ScanningAppProvider.java:118)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:59)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.DeploymentManager.startAppProvider(DeploymentManager.java:552)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.DeploymentManager.doStart(DeploymentManager.java:227)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:59)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AggregateLifeCycle.doStart(AggregateLifeCycle.java:58)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:53)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.doStart(HandlerWrapper.java:91)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:263)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:59)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration$1.run(XmlConfiguration.java:1215)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration.main(XmlConfiguration.java:1138)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.start.Main.invokeMain(Main.java:457)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.start.Main.start(Main.java:602)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.start.Main.main(Main.java:82)
2012-03-01 16:46:03.250:INFO:oejs.AbstractConnector:Started SelectChannelConnector@0.0.0.0:8080
```

I do not know how to resolve it.

Answer (score 4):

Here is what worked for me. Find the Eclipse launch configuration for your Jetty server and open it for editing. Under classpath add all of the jars from /lib (and subdirectories), plus the /start.jar. Try running.

Comment: This works for me.  My problem is Eclipse is smart enough to include  jars in jetty-distribution-8.1.9.v20130131/lib in the server classpath, but sub-folders of lib (e.g. lib/annotations) are omitted, leading to the error above.

Comment: For the eclipse Jetty plugin users, double click on Eclipse on the server tab, then click on 'open launch configuration', then go the classpath tab, add the libraries under {jetty}/lib/annotations as pointed out by Kyle above.

Answer (score 3):

Actually I think the core issue is that plugin is not using the start.ini in the jetty distribution that it unpacks...if it did then it would get annotations support correctly out of the box.  If I remember right the plugin constructs much of the commandline used to start the instance dynamically.  I seem to remember that there was a way to modify the start.ini used in the plugin so it could be its just an old copy of that start.ini that is missing the OPTIONS line with annotations on it.  If you have the ability to tweak that start.ini via the plugin make sure both the OPTIONS line is correct and that jetty-annotations.xml is being processed at the bottom of the file.

Anyway, we have added gerrit support to the git repository housing the plugin so if anyone is interested in contributing updates to the plugin I would be more then happy to review them and push out some updates to the plugin, I just don't have the time to work on that plugin much at the moment.

I suspect this is related to: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=338621

Comment: For 8.1.4, [this comment is the solution](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=338621#c10); the jars in the lib/annotation subdirectory are missing.

Comment: not following, just downloaded it and checked there is a lib/annotations directory with javax.anno and objectweb asm in it...missing the (s) on annotations perhaps?

Comment: @Chris, thanks for the link. But what's missing are not jars, rather they are missed in classpath of the jetty eclipse plugin configuration.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue while running Jetty Server, you need to download and add the asm-3.1.jar to the project classpath.

Answer (score 0):

For some reason the jetty launcher used in eclipse ignores libraries in `lib/subfolders` do either, copy `lib/annotations` libraries to the `lib/` folder or create symbolic links (linux or mac)

```
$ cd folder_to_jetty_installation/lib
$ for i in */*.jar; do; ln -s $i .; done
```