# Maven Jetty Run Error: No ClassVisitor

Tags: maven, maven-jetty-plugin

I'm try to run a system my group made using Maven and Eclipse, but when I try to use mvn jetty:run, this error appears:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/objectweb/asm/ClassVisitor
    at org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationConfiguration.configure(AnnotationConfiguration.java:52)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:975)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:586)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:349)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.plugin.JettyWebAppContext.doStart(JettyWebAppContext.java:102)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:55)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.doStart(HandlerCollection.java:165)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.doStart(ContextHandlerCollection.java:162)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:55)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.doStart(HandlerCollection.java:165)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:55)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.doStart(HandlerWrapper.java:92)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:228)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.plugin.JettyServer.doStart(JettyServer.java:69)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:55)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.plugin.AbstractJettyMojo.startJetty(AbstractJettyMojo.java:433)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.plugin.AbstractJettyMojo.execute(AbstractJettyMojo.java:377)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.plugin.JettyRunMojo.execute(JettyRunMojo.java:546)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultPluginManager.java:490)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoals(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:694)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeStandaloneGoal(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:569)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoal(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:539)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoalAndHandleFailures(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:387)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeTaskSegments(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:348)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.execute(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:180)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:328)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:138)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:362)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.compat.CompatibleMain.main(CompatibleMain.java:60)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:315)
    at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:255)
    at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:430)
    at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:375)
2012-07-10 13:35:25.948:INFO::Started SelectChannelConnector@0.0.0.0:8080
[INFO] Started Jetty Server
[INFO] Starting scanner at interval of 10 seconds.
```

My teammate's systems can run it fine, and we basically have the same settings, repositories, and we are all using Maven2.

Any ideas as to why the error occurs?

Comment: It is very useful question for me. The same (exactly the second, first was missing jersey-bundle in .pom file) problem I had had in Eclipse after installation JAX-RS Glassfish library.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you appear to be needing the `asm` library. The `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError` means you simply don't have the `org.objectweb.asm.ClassVisitor` class on your classpath. I don't know which version of the Jetty plugin you're using, (if you'd paste your `pom.xml`), I could be more precise.

Basically, you need one of these dependencies:

Either add this in your project's `<dependencies/>`:

```
 <dependency>
    <groupId>asm</groupId>
    <artifactId>asm</artifactId>
    <version>3.3.1</version>
 </dependency>
```

Or add this as a `<dependency>` of your Jetty plugin:

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
   <artifactId>jetty-runner</artifactId>
   <version>8.1.0.RC4</version>
</dependency>
```

(Apparently, this dependency contains the ASM classes).

In the future, in order to resolve noclassdef-s, I'd recommend you look up the dependencies the class is part of via some site like:

- http://www.mvnrepository.net/
- http://www.jarvana.com/
- http://search.maven.org/ (using 'Advanced Search')
- http://www.findjar.com/

Comment: But this dependency should already be part of the Maven Jetty plugin. This should not be added explicitly to the pom.

Comment: No, this is not exactly true. But I do agree that he should try removing his repository.

Comment: The asm dependency is already included in the pom.xml, yet the error still occurs.

Comment: It's a problem with the eclipse-jetty-plugin and solved in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9526604/jetty-8-1-1-v20120215-in-eclipse-with-webapp-jsf-maven

Answer (score 0):

If it works for your colleagues but not for you, then it may be due to a corrupt local repository on your machine. Try renaming or deleting your local repository directory to force Maven to download your plugins and dependencies again.